# Can I use inheritance where class names are the only change in java?

Tags: java, arrays, class, inheritance

I have repeating code where the only difference in the code is the Class names and their passed in parameters.
Is there a way to reuse this code?

```
public void addToStaffList(Staff staff)
{
    if(this.staffList == null)
    {
        this.staffList = new Staff[]{staff};
        return;
    }
    if(!isThisStaffAlreadyListed(staff))
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < this.getStaffList().length; i++)
        { // first fill any empty array index
            if(this.getStaffList()[i] == null)
            {
                this.getStaffList()[i] = staff;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    if(!isThisStaffAlreadyListed(staff))
    {
        int length = this.getStaffList().length;
        length++;
        Staff[] newStaffList = new Staff[length];
        for(int i = 0; i < this.getStaffList().length; i++)
        { // add staff to extended array with bigger index
            newStaffList[i] = this.getStaffList()[i];
        }
        newStaffList[newStaffList.length-1] = staff;
        this.staffList = newStaffList;
    }
}
```

this is the same as ....

```
public void addToRoomsList(Room room)
{
    if(this.roomsList == null)
    {
        this.roomsList = new Room[]{room};
        return;
    }
    if(!isThisRoomAlreadyListed(room))
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < this.getRoomsList().length; i++)
        { // first fill any empty array index
            if(this.getRoomsList()[i] == null)
            {
                this.getRoomsList()[i] = room;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    if(!isThisRoomAlreadyListed(room))
    {
        int length = this.getRoomsList().length;
        length++;
        Room[] newRoomsList = new Room[length];
        for(int i = 0; i < this.getRoomsList().length; i++)
        { // add room to extended array with bigger index
            newRoomsList[i] = this.getRoomsList()[i];
        }
        newRoomsList[newRoomsList.length-1] = room;
        this.roomsList = newRoomsList;
    }
}
```

The only difference in these blocks of code are the class names 'Staff' and 'Room' and there parameter variables 'staff' and 'room'.
Even in these blocks of code there is more repeated blocks like `isThisStaffAlreadyListed()` and `isThisRoomAlreadyListed()` both have blocks of code in them that are the same except for the Class names that change.
Is there a way I can reuse this code by somehow passing in the Class names and their parameters?

Comment: Read about generics. Also, I guess that's for a course and you're not allowed to use lists, but there's really no reason to use an array here.

Comment: Stop using arrays and start using collections, namely `Set` seems appropriate for your use case if you properly implement `equals` and `hashCode` on your objects. With that all your code would boil down to few lines of code. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html

Comment: You could put all the code you want to reuse in an abstract class or interface and your more specialized classes could extend it. Along the way methods with identical functionality could be lumped by renaming them more generally such as simply asTo() and isAlreadyListed()

Comment: To emphasize what  Pavel Horal said: The "root problem" here is not the code duplication, because this only stems from the fact that you're using arrays. I guess the `is...AlreadyListed` methods perform a linear search, which is bad in terms of complexity, as well as extending the array size by 1 for each added element. Consider replacing the `roomList` by a `LinkedHashSet<Room> rooms`, then your whole methods would disappear, and you could just write `rooms.add(room);` - this would be *much* easier, *much* more concise and idiomatic and *much* more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

The bulk of your code looks for an opening in an array, and expands the array by one element if there is not enough space.

If you are limited to using arrays, one way to reuse your code would be making a generic helper method that expands the array, like this:

```
public <T> T[] fitOrExpand(T[] a, T item, Class<T> type) {
    if (a == null) {
        T[] res = (T[])Array.newInstance(type, 1);
        res[0] = item;
        return res;
    }
    for (int i = 0 ; i != a.length ; i++) {
        if (a[i] == null) {
            a[i] = item;
            return a;
        }
    }
    T[] res = (T[])Array.newInstance(type, a.length+1);
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, res, 0, a.length);
    res[res.length-1] = item;
    return res;
}
```

You need to import `java.lang.reflect.Array` in order for this to compile.

This is almost exactly your code, with three exceptions:

- It assumes that the room or the staff is not listed. You would have to check it separately,
- It uses a generic type `T` instead of specific types in your code, and
- It uses [`System.arraycopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) instead of a second loop.

With this method in hand, you can rewrite both methods like this:

```
public void addToStaffList(Staff staff) {
    if(isThisStaffAlreadyListed(staff)) return;
    this.staffList == fitOrExpand(this.staffList, staff, Staff.class);
}

public void addToRoomsList(Room room) {
    if(isThisRoomAlreadyListed(room)) return;
    this.roomsList == fitOrExpand(this.roomsList, room, Room.class);
}
```

If you can use `ArrayList<T>`, you could simplify this even further: if you declare your `staffList` and `roomList` like this

```
List<Room> roomList = new ArrayList<Room>();
List<Staff> staffList = new ArrayList<Staff>();
```

your helper method would look like this:

```
static <T> void fitOrExpand(List<T> list, T item) {
    // No null checking of the entire list is necessary,
    // because we created an empty list.
    // Go straight to null-checking elements:
    for (int i = 0 ; i != list.size() ; i++) {
        if (list.get(i) == null) {
            list.put(i, item);
            return;
        }
    }
    list.add(item);
}
```

The two calls will look like this:

```
public void addToStaffList(Staff staff) {
    if(isThisStaffAlreadyListed(staff)) return;
    fitOrExpand(this.staffList, staff);
}

public void addToRoomsList(Room room) {
    if(isThisRoomAlreadyListed(room)) return;
    fitOrExpand(this.roomsList, room);
}
```

Comment: I'd still recommend using an `ArrayList` instead of this ad-hoc solution, if one does not have very good reasons to use arrays.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Indeed that's my feeling too, but we don't know for sure. Anyway, if the OP hasn't learnt yet about Java collections, I seriously doubt that using a generic method is in the range of his skills (or allowed features).

Comment: I can use anything I can learn, I am not limited in assignments, however I need to be able to understand what it is I am using. I kind of understand ArrayList but have no idea about generic collections

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are looking for is named [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/). Your code might look like

```
abstract class MyList<T> {
    public int size() {...}
    protected void addToList(T elem) {
        // insert your common code here
        // and use T instead of Staff/Room
    }
}

class StuffList extends MyList<Stuff> {
   public void addStuffToList(Stuff stuff) {addToList(stuff);}
}
```

or

```
class MyList<T> {
    public int size() {...}
    protected void addToList(T elem) {...}
}

class StuffList {
   private MyList<Stuff> list = new MyList<>();
   public void addStuffToList(Stuff stuff) {list.addToList(stuff);}
   public int size() { list.size(); }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, generics are relevant but your answer (minus the link) does not actually explain anything or have anything to do with OPs _specific_ problem (which is IMO _too broad_ for SO, as OP seems to be a beginner in java).

Comment: @l4mpi I don't think the OP's question is too broad at all. Generics is exactly what the OP is looking for. This answer is not perfectly complete, but it still does help. Anyway, I don't think this deserves a downvote, it could help more, but it is already helpful. It is not misleading or anything

Comment: Why the `size()` method? The generic class would contain the exact same code as the OP's original code, except for the class name which will be written as `T`. But there is no use for a `size()` method in the OP's code, as it uses an array internally, with `length`.

Comment: @Joffrey OPs question, at this point, is basically "how do I turn this code dump into something I can use for different classes" - _too broad_ by far. And this answer is so far into _not useful_ territory that I don't know how anybody can upvote it. It says "use generics" and then gives useless examples, as they are in no way helpful for changing OPs code into a generic method.

Comment: @l4mpi The OP's question is: "What in Java could help reuse code where only the class changes?", and there is no huge *"code dump"*, but just a method and its duplicate. It has a very short and narrow answer: use generics (absolutely ***not** too broad*). Then you can elaborate by showing how the OP can change his code using generics, which is what Stas Kurilin did (I added a comment in the code to clarify for the OP).

Comment: @Joffrey the _short_ answer is completely useless (you could just as well say "use foobar"), and the elaboration in this answer is useless as well. It is, without explanation, just another random code dump. The only useful thing in this answer is IMO the link to the generics tutorial, and well, that's an external link and not an actual part of the answer.

Comment: Seems like OP is not aware of Java collections and is not familiar with the language... so suggesting advanced topic like generics will probably not help (just my two cents on this topic).

Comment: @PavelHoral on the contrary, I think it _could_ help, just that OP probably needs a full tutorial or at least a far better explanation than just dumping a few lines of uncommented example code - which is in turn too broad for SO.

Comment: @PavelHoral indeed, but this is not for us to decide. OP's asking for a feature, so giving him the feature is never a bad idea. If he doesn't feel like having the skill to use it, then he'll just walk away and keep the duplication, but for everyone, this is the answer to the question.

Comment: @l4mpi Then you agree that the problem does not lie in the OP's question. You're just not satisfied with the answer, yet.

Comment: @Joffrey the problem lies in _both_, actually. OP is clearly a java beginner and thus a suitable answer would have to pick them up at their level of knowledge, which is _unclear_ to begin with, and this answer fails to do so. It also makes it hard for this question to ever become a useful reference (which is what SO aims to be, we're not any random help site after all). At least it has received a high quality answer from blinkenlight, which is somewhat useful because it actually gives a good example and explains it a bit.

Comment: @Joffrey I added `size()` method to show how the methods with same signature would work with inheritance/composition approach. I don't really think that solving problem is better than showing the way is better for learning purpose.

Comment: yeah im a beginner, never used a list or generics before. I do not understand either of the examples given but I am going to follow the link now and see if that helps to explain a solution

Comment: @StasKurilin I see, but I think this part is just misleading, and also it doesn't really show an example of type reuse through generics, it just shows abtract inheritance.